# Python finding text in items

Tags: python

I want to find best solution for following situation:
i got following items:
`item1` which contain `test1` and `test2`
`item2` which contain `test3` and `test4`
and
`item3` which contain `test5`
And `superItem` which contain `item1`,`item2` and `item3`

Which methods should I use to achive following results;
I got a variable `check` which contain `test1`
I want to receive in `result` variable `item1`...

In another words:
I want to receive name of item which contain same text as in variable `check`

What is the best solution?

Comment: @CédricJulien dictionary of sets, but i cant understand how to named sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you will hold these variables in the dictionary like in the code below.

```
container = {
    'item1': {'test1', 'test2'},
    'item2': {'test3', 'test4'},
    'item3': {'test5'}
}
    }
check = 'test1'

for key in container:
    if check in container[key]:
        break

result = container[key]
print result
```

**EDIT**

I added sets for you - you use `{ }` for them.

Comment: Thanks alot, Actually with using ` [ ] ` you were right,
and also for me there must be `result = key`

Answer (score 2):

A simple version using string items and list comprehension :

```
item1 = ["test1", "test2"]
item2 = ["test3", "test4"]
item3 = ["test5"]
superItem = [item1, item2, item3]

check = "test1"
result = [item for item in superItem if check in item]

>>> result
[["test1", "test2"]]
```

Comment: @Pepelac : without more informations on what you did and/or examples, I thought that sets could help you. If you add some precisions to your question, I could maybe help you more precisely ;)

Comment: Yes it's exacly what i has tried, but actually i have all item in super item at they defenition + in results I need `Item1` as a text

Answer (score 1):

My implementation which utilises list comprehension. List name ('itemn') is stored in superItem dict so you can get it when needed.

```
item1 = ["test1", "test2"]
item2 = ["test3", "test4"]
item3 = ["test5"]

superItem = {
    'item1': item1,
    'item2': item2,
    'item3': item3
}

check = "test1"

result = [x for x in superItem if check in superItem[x]]

print result
```

Performance test:

```
$ time python2.7 sometest.py 
['item1']

real    0m0.315s
user    0m0.191s
sys 0m0.077s
```